# Faking AD while debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I have an MVC intranet application, and I wish to make my life easier!
When I'm developing I don't have access to the AD, so I have to publish to test... annoying!
So I was thinking, when I'm in debug mode I'd want to fake AD login somehow.

When launching the application (in debug mode) the fake AD user could be set on a page which the client will redirect you to or via URL params.

Any suggestions on how this could be done? Any tools?

Comment: Hey you need to have access to the AD. How can you test it then if it is working

Comment: I logon to a remote desktop check out solution from svn and run it there. It's quite the hazzle.

Comment: I think mocking the ldap/Active Directory class would be a solution for you... Never worked in asp so I am not sure what's available there but most modern programming/scripting languages have libraries for mocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way! Kudos to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603838/programmatically-refresh-update-httpcontext-user) answer.

You can fake the current user the following way. It even supports roles.

```
#if DEBUG
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
{
    var roles = new[] { "Role1", "Role2" };
    HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("DebugUser"), roles);

    base.OnAuthorization(context);
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I install a Directory in a virtual machine running on my development environement  by the past, I was using ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode) directly installed on my XP. You can install LDS (Lightweigh Directory Server) on Seven or Windows 8.

This way you just need to change your configuration file in debug mode.

Comment: Setting up a local server doesn't seem worth the time, plus it's not very "portable". By that I mean I can't switch machine/location and have it still work. I guess I'm looking for a way to set User.Identity, possibly using #if DEBUG compiler flags. It has to be simple and easy else it's not worth the time.