# How to easy hold a User object that is logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I easy hold a user object when it is logged in?

I have a login system now but for instance when I want to go to the details page of that user, I pass the userid (thats in the viewbag of the view) to the ActionResult Details(int userId).

In the Details ActionResult I then use the userId to find the user in the UserRepository. But this seems to create alot of unnecessary work for the database.

Isn't there a more easy way? Maybe create a global variable of the User?

I don't want to work with sessions, as this could create problems when I deploy my project (multi-server).

I use this code to make a AuthorizationCookie when the user logs in:

```
            if (IsValid(user.Email, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
                ViewBag.UserId = user.UserId;

                return RedirectToAction("News", "Home");
            }
```

Comment: There is no point adding a property to `ViewBag` if you then redirect (its immediately lost)

Comment: I use the viewbag to add a parameter when I call Details in the view

Comment: It will be `null`. `ViewBag` only lives for the current request and is used for passing data from the controller to the view. If you redirect it becomes `null`. As for using a global variable, unless there will only ever be one user, then no, its not suitable. What wrong with doing it the standard way and getting it from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to look at the ASP.Net Identity
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

This framework has support for all Authentication and Authorization features.

Thanks and Regards,

Sam Jayander Thiagarajan.

Comment: But the authorization works perfect, I just don't want to pass the userId between everything

Comment: try using the HttpContext.Current.User. http://stackoverflow.com/a/654590/1624437

Comment: I can do this: HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; and that gives me the correct name of the currently logged in user, however, I still need to go to the database to get the user. Maybe it isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

FormsAuthentication class has string UserData property. You can put there whatever you want.

```
User myUser = new User();
myUser.Name = 'John';
myUser.Age = '16';
string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myUser);
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1/*version*/, myUserName, DateTime.Now,     DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), 1/*isPersitant*/, userData);
```

Inside the action about user details you can write something like that and get your user details

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
 if (authCookie != null)
    {
      FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
  User currentUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(authTicket.UserData);
```